# CouchDB/PouchDB design documents query with startkey endkey not working

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

In my database I have (not only) two types of documents in a one-to-many relationship. I tried to manage this like the following example shows:

```
{ 
  _id : "class:xyz"
  type: "class"
  ... other keys ...
}

{
  _id : "class:xyz:pupil:abc"
  type: "pupil"
  ... other keys ...
}
```

If I query my docs with `allDocs()` like

```
http://url_of_my_server:5984/my_database/_all_docs?include_docs=true&?startkey="class:xyz:pupil:"&endkey="class:xyz:pupil:\ufff0"
```

I get all docs of type `pupil` related to the mentioned doc of type `class` like wanted.

For performance I had the idea to introduce a design document to query only the docs of type `pupil` and not all docs every time:

```
{
  "_id": "_design/types",
  "language": "javascript",
  "views": {
    "classes": {
      "map": "function(doc){ if(doc.type == \"class\"){emit(doc.id, doc);} }"
    },
    "pupils": {
      "map": "function(doc){ if(doc.type == \"pupil\"){emit(doc.id, doc);} }"
    },
  }
}
```

But if I query with this design document like

```
http://url_of_my_server:5984/my_database/_design/types/_view/pupils?include_docs=true&?startkey="class:xyz:pupil:"&endkey="class:xyz:pupil:\ufff0"
```

I get no result (only an empty array/no rows).

Where is my mistake or what is wrong in my conception? I actually have no idea? Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: That URL is bad in a few ways, namely it requires some [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) e.g. `:` is reserved. Also get rid of the the double quotes. Fix the URL and you should get results.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but changing `:` to `%3A` and `"` to `%22` doesn't change unlikely anything.

Comment: Yeah you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, for a view *never* `emit` the document as a value; it is quite redundant since one may use `include_docs=true` - and worse, it consumes storage unnecessarily.

Assuming two documents

```json
{
  _id : "class:xyz:pupil:abc"
  type: "pupil"  
},
{
  _id : "class:xyz:pupil:xyz"
  type: "pupil"  
}
```

And the map function for `pupils`

```json
"pupils": {
  "map": "function(doc){ if(doc.type == \"pupil\"){emit(doc.id, doc);} }"
}
```

The view index for `pupils` looks like this

| id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| class:xyz:pupil:abc | null | {"_id": "class:xyz:pupil:abc", /* etc */ } |
| class:xyz:pupil:xyz | null | {"_id": "class:xyz:pupil:xyz", /* etc */ } |

So the `key` columns are **null** because the map function is emitting `doc.id` as the key.

See it? `doc.id` is undefined - `emit(doc._id)` instead.

Fix the design document map functions (including not emitting doc as value)

```json
{
  "_id": "_design/types",   
  "views": {
    "classes": {
      "map": "function(doc){ if(doc.type == \"class\"){emit(doc._id);} }"
    },
    "pupils": {
      "map": "function(doc){ if(doc.type == \"pupil\"){emit(doc._id);} }"
    }
  }
}
```

Given the two hypothetical documents, the `pupils` index now looks like this

| id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| class:xyz:pupil:abc | class:xyz:pupil:abc | null |
| class:xyz:pupil:xyz | class:xyz:pupil:abc | null |

Now that the view index's `key` has a value the query will operate as intended.

I highly recommend using Fauxton as it provides a quick means to view an index among other things.

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me a lot. Now I know it better and understand the concept of design documents.